# Moving the circle in the directing of another circle revolving around it in canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, canvas, p5.js

I have a problem of moving the big circle in the direction of small circle when a button is pressed. can anyone help?

Goals:

1. Make a circle on canvas [Done]
2. Draw a small circle that rotates around the big circle [Done]
3. Move the big circle for 5 pixels when a button is pressed in the direction of small circle pointing at that time [pending]
4. add a drawing effect while moving [pending]

can we can use the coordinates of x and y in below at the point of button press and move the main circle in the direction? correct me if i am wrong

```
let x = r *2* cos(angle);


let y = r *2* sin(angle);
```

```js
let angle = 0;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
}



function draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(4);
  let cir = createVector(200,200);
  let velocity = createVector();
  
  
  
  
  let r = 10;
  k = circle(cir.x, cir.y, r * 2);

  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(255);
  let x = r *2* cos(angle);
  let y = r *2* sin(angle);
  translate(200,200);
  point(x, y);
  angle += 0.01;
  
  if(mouseIsPressed){
    k.x += x;
    k.y += y;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the big circle in the direction of the small circle while keeping the small circle orbiting around the big circle by keeping track of the big circle's center.

Move the variable `cir` outside of draw so we hang on to any changes made to it.

We also need to calculate a move that is 5px along the line segment from the big circle's center and the small circle. To do this we can use the formula in this solution [to find a point on a line segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134138/653445)

To prevent the small circle from rotating during the move we can increment the rotation angle only when the mouse is not down.

```js
let angle = 0;
let cir;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  cir = createVector(200,200);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(4);
  let r = 10;
  circle(cir.x, cir.y, r * 2);
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(255);
  let x = r *2* cos(angle);
  let y = r *2* sin(angle);
  point(x +cir.x, y+cir.y);
 
  
  if(mouseIsPressed){ 
    cir.x = (1-0.025)*cir.x+0.025*(x+cir.x);
    cir.y = (1-0.025)*cir.y+0.025*(y+cir.y);
  } else {
   angle += 0.01;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. can you explain this line `cir.x = (1-0.025)*cir.x+0.025*(x+cir.x);` and why you took those values.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the rotation of the small circle at the time of movement and resume after stopping?.

Comment: Yes, see my modified code. To stop rotation we just skip incrementing the angle.

Comment: cir.x = (1-0.025)*cir.x+0.025*(x+cir.x); calculates the new x pos of the large circle by plugging the big circle center point and the small circle position into the formula for finding a point on a line segment. See the link for more details.

Comment: Thanks, quick question, How can we add acceleration to this?. I have tried adding, it is speeding up but it is not changing its direction. when I just increasing the value of 0.025 it's working, but I need to steadily increase its velocity. can you please help

Comment: Please look into this code that I have updated. https://codepen.io/harshasatyavardhan/pen/KKNOmwL?editors=0010 I made it to draw while moving but after some time it's getting slow, u can observe if u press the mouse and watch sometime. I don't know why it's happening, I think maybe the coordinates are getting accumulated in the list and making it to crash. please help correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @harsha satya vardhan ask a new question and post the code that is having the slow down issue. Also ask another question about acceleration and I am sure someone will have a good answer for you